# Support British spelling on CV/developer story

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I typically use British spelling, as that's how I was taught and because I currently live in the UK. So I also also use British spelling on my CV/developer story.

But the text Stack Overflow provides is always in American English. Nothing wrong with that, as such, but it's not consistent with the text I wrote.

Example:

[image: Favourite!]

Could there be an option to add these terms in British English, rather than American English?

Comment: Slightly related on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254756/158100

Comment: I'm not British, but I can't tell the difference any more. Colour, color...whichever (I read too many books by British authors).